# Echo variable defined as result from command line resets cursor position

Tags: bash

If I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=$(< ds.tmp)
echo "Hello${HOSTNAME}!"

TEST="1.2.3.4"
echo "Hello${TEST}!"
```

With the contents of `ds.tmp` only an ip address (say 1.2.3.4), the result is:

```
!ello1.2.3.4
Hello1.2.3.4!
```

So after I print a variable that is assigned by a `$(...)`, the cursor position is reset and it overwrites all text.

Why is this? I have looked everywhere but cannot find a reference this anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
HOSTNAME=$(tr -d "\r" < ds.tmp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `ds.tmp` file has `CR-LF` as its line breaks. As a result, `${HOSTNAME}` contains `1.2.3.4\r`, not just `1.2.3.4`.

Unix text files should just use `LF` as their line breaks. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.